# How to create a common constant instance of a self-defined object in javascript?

Tags: javascript, constants

I'm creating a program to represent a binary search tree in javascript. What I want is a way to create a common tree node with both ptrs(left, right) as null. This is the code i wrote:

```
var BST = function(data) {
    if (data === null || data === undefined){
        this.data  = null;
        this.left  = null;
        this.right = null;
    }

    else{
        this.data  = data;
        this.left  = new BST(null);
        this.right = new BST(null);
    }
};

BST.prototype.insert = function(data) {
    if (this.data === null){
        this.data  = data;
        this.left  = new BST(null);
        this.right = new BST(null);
    }
    else if (data < this.data)
        this.left.insert(data);
    else if (data > this.data)
        this.right.insert(data);
};

BST.prototype.inOrder = function(func) {
    if (this.data !== null) {
        this.left.inOrder(func);
        func(this.data);
        this.right.inOrder(func);
    }
};
```

Here, i want to assign all null pointers with a null node(as defined in the `if(data === null || data === undefined)` condition). But for every null node I'm having to create a new node representing the same data.
Is there a way to assign to a common instance of the null node?
The reason i use a null node instead of just using

```
else{
    this.data = data;
    this.left = null;
    this.right = null;
}
```

is that on calling the `inOrder` method, on reaching a node with `left or right = null`, it gives a `TypeError` because it tries to run  `null.inOrder(func);` since, `this.left` translates to `null`.
The way around that is to modify the `inOrder` function, which will lead to many conditions around each statement, i.e. not a very elegant implementation.
I could also define `inOrder` outside the prototype of the object, and make it take a tree as an argument i.e. `inOder(tree,func)`, but I don't want to do that.

Also, as a second improvement to the code, consider the `insert` method; in the  `null` case:

```
if (this.data === null){
    this.data  = data;
    this.left  = new BST(null);
    this.right = new BST(null);
}
```

since I have to override each entry anyway, I want to reassign this node to a new Tree altogether by doing something along the lines of:

```
if (this.data === null)
    this = new BST(data);
```

I am aware that this would be a less efficient implementation to the former, but it is still a lot more concise.So is there any way to do so?

Comment: You can't assign to `this`, instead you will need to manipulate the parent node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But for every null node I'm having to create a new node representing the same data. Is there a way to assign to a common instance of the null node?

Yes, but this would break your code. Think about it: what happens when you call the `insert` method on that node instance? ...

As for the second problem, you cannot optimize that with your current model. There is no such thing as in-place object replacement ([there is in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5562908/assignment-of-a-struct-value-to-this-keyword)).

I think your current code is ok, though I'd personally stick with a simpler model, something like

```
var BST = function(data) {
    this.insert(data);
};

BST.prototype.insert = function(data) {
    if (typeof this.data == 'undefined') {
        this.data = data;
    } else if (data < this.data) {
        if (!this.left) {
            this.left = new BST();
        }
        this.left.insert(data);
    } else if (data > this.data) {
        if (!this.right) {
            this.right = new BST();
        }
        this.right.insert(data);
    }
};

BST.prototype.inOrder = function(func) {
    if (typeof this.data != 'undefined') {
        this.left && this.left.inOrder(func);
        func(this.data);
        this.right && this.right.inOrder(func);
    }
};
```

Note that this completely eliminates the need for a `nullNode`, since - hey! - it's JavaScript, so why not use such wonderful things as `undefined` and dynamic object extension.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in this case you can use a constant instance because all null-nodes are the same and don't have different references (like a "parent" property). To create such a constant you will need a place to store it; that can either be a (private) variable or something like

```
BST.emptyleaf = new BST(null);
```

And you could also use the singleton pattern:

```
function BST(data) {
    if (data === null || data === undefined) {
        if (BST.emptyleaf)
            return BST.emptyleaf; // singleton instance if available
        this.data  = null;
        this.left  = null;
        this.right = null;
        BST.emptyleaf = this; // else create it for re-use
    } else {
        this.data  = data;
        this.left  = new BST(null);
        this.right = new BST(null);
    }
}
```